# HDMI Output Not Working Properly

Tags: sound, multiple-monitors, video, resolution, hdmi

[image]

[image]

Excuse my bad photographs but hopefully they help to illustrate the problems I'm having. The colour is messed up and does not look as it should. In addition to this I also do not have any audio output (although this isn't something that bothers me).

Any help at all is greatly appreciated.

If this helps at all I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (64 bit).

Comment: did you try changing the resolution of the second monitor?
about the color, it depends on your second monitor settings. mine wont be as colorful as my laptop because the monitor is an old lcd and stuff, while my laptop screen is a new model with some extra technology

Comment: I don't know if you can tell from the photographs but the laptop is a MacBook Pro so I know the monitor won't look nearly as good as it. It does however output no problem at all on OS X with the colours being completely fine. Is there a particular setting in Ubuntu I need to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem seems to have fixed itself. Possibly due to the fact that I've changed video drivers from Nouveau to the NVIDIA binary driver.